# function to copy openoffice comments to a cell

Tags: function, macros, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to import spreadsheet data into a CMS, but there are around 100 comments on various cells throughout the 4000+ row spreadsheet that we would like to import also. Is there a function or macro that will copy the comment content into a cell? (not as a comment, just as plain text)

Comment: Please be more specific. "...copy the comment content into a cell?" Into what cell? The same cell which is commented? What about the cell content then? Shall the comment simply be appended to the content? What about numeric cell content then? That content will be not numeric after that action.

Answer (score 1):

In [Openoffice API](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html) the [interface XSheetAnnotationsSupplier](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetAnnotationsSupplier.html) provides a method `getAnnotations`. Using this it is possible to get all sheet annotations together with their positions. The Position is the address of the cell in which the annotation is placed:

```
sub getAnnotations()

 oThisWorkbook = ThisComponent
 oActiveSheet = oThisWorkbook.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

 oAnnotations = oActiveSheet.Annotations

 for each oAnnotation in oAnnotations
  lColumn = oAnnotation.Position.Column
  lRow = oAnnotation.Position.Row
  sText = oAnnotation.String

  oCell = oActiveSheet.getCellByPosition(lColumn, lRow)

  msgbox oCell.AbsoluteName & " has annotation: " & sText
 next

end sub
```

So you have the annotations (comments) and their cells.

Now you have to decide what you wants to do with that. As said in my comment already, simply appending the annotations to the cell contents is not a good idea in my opinion. That will possibly make the cell content unreadable for further processing.